# Uploaded Slidify deck to rpubs is blank

Tags: html, r, slidify

I have tried to publish in two different ways, gh-pages and rpubs. Both times, I successfully access the document, but it is just blank. The preview is working, but I can't seem to get the deck uploaded correctly. When I view it in my browser it also works. Is there any way to get around this and upload the html independently?

In trying to resolve the issue, I added this to my .Rprofile:

```
options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal")

options(RCurlOptions = list(verbose = FALSE, capath = system.file
("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl" ), ssl.verifpeer = FALSE))
```

Beyond that, I have been using the function `publish_rpubs` or publishing in RStudio.

Additionally, I get a warning `invalid uid value replaced by that for user 'nobody'`. I am not sure if this has to do with the error.

Comment: For future reference - for me, this had to do with the order in which I had installed my packages.

Comment: which packages?